# NOT NULL constraint failed: trabajador_trabajador.rol_id

Tags: python, django

tengo en siguiente error NOT NULL constraint failed: trabajador_trabajador.rol_id
 al momento de guardar los datos usando un modelForm

Modelo

```
class Trabajador(models.Model):
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rol = models.ForeignKey('Rol', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombres
```

form

```
class Trabajadorform(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Trabajador
        fields = ['nombres', 'apellido_paterno', 'apellido_materno']
```

vista

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import Trabajadorform


def registrar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Trabajadorform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('formulario valido')
            trabajador = form.save()
            trabajador.save()
            #return redirect('post_detail')
    else:
        form = Trabajadorform

    return render(request, 'registrar_trabajador.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes el campo rol vacío. Django por defecto pone todos los campos obligatorios. No sé si es así como lo quieres así que te daré 2 soluciones:

### solución Rol vacío

Modifica el campo rol en tu modelo por este:

```
class Trabajador(models.Model):
    nombres = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_paterno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    apellido_materno = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    rol = models.ForeignKey('Rol', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

### Solución Rol no vacío

Añade el campo al `ModelForm` para que así puedas añadir un rol a ese trabajador o puedes añadirle el propio rol dentro de la view haciendole `trabajador.rol = Rol.objects.get(id=id_ejemplo)` y luego aplicarle el `save()`